# Error:Failed to notify build operation listener. > java/lang/Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter

Tags: android

there is issue in dependencies and the following error is appearing

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    releaseImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please update your question with stack trace.